# Error in JavaFX WebView listener for click event while trying to record that a click has been performed on a page

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

The primary purpose is to Print "*click operation has been performed*" in the console, if any click is performed on the page loaded in the embedded browser, for achieving the aforementioned behavior I got the below code, it shows error.

```
    ((EventTarget) el).addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

Here is the complete code snippet: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html

```
        EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
        System.out.println("Click Operation has been performed");
    }
};
Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
Element el = doc.getElementById("dummyid");
((EventTarget) el).addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

Comment: I am new to JavaFx and Webengine, any sort of guidance, correction or suggestion will be great.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the link you've provided, you can call java methods by using JSObject.setMember method.

```
public class JavaApplication {
    public void exit() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
...
JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("app", new JavaApplication());
```

You can call from the web page

```
<a href="" onclick="app.exit()">Click here to exit application</a>
```

This could be an alternative solution instead of using handlers